# Flutter Firestore throwing Google Playstore exception on emulator

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, android-emulator

I am using Firebase auth and Firebase Firestore.  My auth implementation i working fine. As soon as I hooked the Firebase Firestore, I keep getting a FATAL error that Google Playstore service is needed. I am running on Pixel_3a_API_30_x86 emulator.   Firestore does not require Google Play service as per the google documentation.  I am not sure why is this happening. I have googled but nothing have I found.  On a different emulator, it is working fine.  I am using a Mac.  Here is the error reported in IDE.  Thanks in advance for any advise.

```
/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3512): Google Play Store is missing.
E/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3512): GooglePlayServices not available due to error 9
W/Firestore( 3512): (23.0.4) [GrpcCallProvider]: Failed to update ssl context: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException
I/TetheringManager( 3512): registerTetheringEventCallback:com.theshuk.rental
W/.theshuk.renta( 3512): Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (greylist-max-q,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
W/.theshuk.renta( 3512): Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/AbstractConscryptSocket;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (greylist-max-q, reflection, denied)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3512): FATAL EXCEPTION: grpc-okhttp-0
```

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation it turns out the exception is pertaining to grpc-okhttp-0.  Even though GooglePlayServicesUtil is reported as E ( Errors ) it still continues.

The grpc-okhttp-0 exception happens only on some emulators, not all. For example pixel 4a works fine. To solve the problem, I added the following to my build.gradle file.

```
implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.41.0"
```

It worked.